# Background audio player

Tags: audio

There are a lot of audio/music players that are either WP plugins or work with WP, but I don't see that they do exactly what I'm looking for. I want to be able to play an audio file automatically when the site loads, as a sort of background music, with the only control a "turn this off" button - no play/pause, no track info etc. (I'm vehemently against this sort of online Muzak, but my client is insistent.)

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For a permanent/persistent audio player I can think of these options:

- a completely Ajaxified theme, so the content is dynamicaly loaded
- put the audio player in a frame and the navigation/content in another one (yes, frames, that thing of the past)
- open the audio player in a pop-up
- make WordPress the CMS but pull the content in a Flash site (visitors see Flash, Google see WP)

Otherwise, it's a completely unfriendly player: at each navigation link clicked the thing restarts playing...

---

**[edit]**
This is the simplest plugin I know and it's easy to style:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/haiku-minimalist-audio-player/

You can find simple and free flash players here:
http://ffiles.com

For feeding a Flash player with WP content, open a new question and drop me a line, as I have written many versions of this kind of interaction.