# Wordpress / Audio player

Tags: media, audio

I need to build a website with an audio player. This audio player needs to play music without stopping when content is loaded. I know this might be a little complicated but I would like to know if this is possible and how I could implement it.

Comment: Plugin recommendation is off-topic ([help/on-topic]) - (it's an historic tag, didn't its description appear to you?). [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56403/12615) may help.

Comment: It didn't, if I know I wouldn't have this tag.

Comment: Yep, but it was easy after all to remove the recommendation. Did you read the linked Answer?